# Configure Nginx to get the content of the relative path

Tags: nginx

I have the following html sites (swagger-ui dashboards) in the same machine (lets say in the cloud)

- http://somewhere_in_the_cloud:8083/swagger-ui.html (trains)
- http://somewhere_in_the_cloud:8087/swagger-ui.html (planes)

I want to avoid to show *somewhere_in_the_cloud* and show another url (swaggerui/trains and swaggerui/planes), that is why I use a Nginx.

I can see the swagger-ui.html, but the content of this site which should be loaded with relatives paths (css, js, ...) is not loaded because the Nginx looks in the root. So, **how should be my nginx.conf file to see swagger-ui.html site which should work and have all of the static content?**

Example of something that I can not see, it has a relative path:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

This is my nginx.conf and what I tried without success:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /swaggerui/trains {
          proxy_pass http://somewhere_in_the_cloud:8083/swagger-ui.html;
        }

        location /swaggerui/planes {
          proxy_pass http://somewhere_in_the_cloud:8087/swagger-ui.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you enforce a trailing `/` so that the relative directory is correct?

Comment: @RichardSmith How could I do that? (Sorry I am new with nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser forms path relative links by looking for the last `/` in the current URI, so the relative resource file `style.css` would be located as follows:

```
/swaggerui/trains -> /swaggerui/style.css
/swaggerui/planes -> /swaggerui/style.css
```

If you enforce a trailing `/` on your initial URIs, the results will be:

```
/swaggerui/trains/ -> /swaggerui/trains/style.css
/swaggerui/planes/ -> /swaggerui/planes/style.css
```

which will find the different resource files.

There are a number of ways to do enforce this. One example would be:

```
location /swaggerui/ {
    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    return 404;
}
location /swaggerui/trains/ {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
location /swaggerui/planes/ {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

The first location block adds a trailing `/` if one is missing. The following two blocks only match URIs which include that third `/`.